# Can ADO.NET DataTables hold data of types other than Object when grabbing data from a SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, types, datatable, ado.net

I'm currently forced to use `System.Data` and `System.Data.SqlClient`, i.e. ADO.NET. I `DataAdapter.Fill` a lot of my `DataTables` with data from my SQL server. I know with absolute certainty that many of the columns will be set up in SQL such that they can only contain `int`s, but ADO.NET doesn't know that. Instead, it assumes that my data is of the `Object` type, meaning that my code is filled with many occurrences of ridiculous `int.Parse(Row["RowName"].ToString())` code. I'd like to cut off this problem at the source and have my C# code know the types of the SQL columns that it's pulling through.

Is there any way to achieve this? I'm aware that `DataColumn`s can be given types and that `DataTable`s are built from them, but I don't know where to make those changes relative to when I'm fetching data from the server. So, for argument's sake, where would I modify this code to communicate that I know for absolutely certain that my columns will always be `int`s?

```cs
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public static DataTable GetEmployeeStatistics(int EmployeeID)
{
    var Command = new SqlCommand("Select [Height], [Weight], [Salary] from [Schema].[Employees] Where EmployeeID = @EmployeeID", GrabMySqlConnection())
    Command.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", EmployeeID)
    var Adapter = new SQLDataAdapter(Command);
    var Tab = new DataTable();
    var Adapter.Fill(Tab)
    return Tab
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `DataTable` will contain the correct column-type int, but since `DataTable`a are very old they are not generic, so all rows contain objects as fields. You have to cast them to `int`. The best you can do is to use the [`Field`-extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.field?view=net-7.0) which is generic and also supports nullable types(for example `int?` if it's nullable in DB).

So instead of this:

```
int.Parse(Row["ColumnName"].ToString())
```

use

```
Row.Field<int>("ColumnName")
```

By the way, your approach was already incorrect because you should not convert an object to string, just to be able to parse it to int. This would be the classic correct way:

```
Convert.ToInt32(Row["ColumnName"])
```

Comment: Microsoft provides some useful examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/generic-field-and-setfield-methods-linq-to-dataset). Just for argument's sake, what happens if you use `Field<int>` on something that is absolutely not an `int`?

Comment: @J.Mini: You will get an `InvalidCastException` at runtime

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this makes me sad:

```
int.Parse(Row["RowName"].ToString())
```

When a Datable column contains an `int` from SQL Server, it *really is an `int`*. That means you can do this:

```
(int)Row["RowName"]
```

It may seem like a minor change, but thanks to cultural/internationalization issues, converting numeric (and datetime) values to and from string is a surprisingly slow and error-prone operation. A basic cast, telling the compiler what the value already is, instead of round-tripping it through two separate string conversions, will be **MUCH** more efficient. The only trick here is to be careful of results that could be `NULL` in the database. That requires a little more code to handle.

---

This also makes me sad:

```
Command.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", EmployeeID)
```

Because of the way ADO.Net does parameter binding with SQL Server, when you let it infer the type it's possible to end up with subtly wrong inferences that cause SQL Server to need to per-row conversions and miss on index use. This can really kill performance. For this case you're probably okay, but generally you're often better off if you're explicit about your database column data type when creating the parameter:

```
Command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = EmployeeID;
```

---

For the actual question, what I tend to do is build a static `FromDataRow()` method for my objects. As an abbreviated example:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Decimal Salary {get;set;}
    public DateTime HireDate {get;set;}
    public int Weight {get;set;}
    public int HeightInInches {get;set}

    public static Employee FromDataRow(DataRow row)
    {
        return new Employee() {
             ID = (int)row["ID"],
             Name = (string)row["Name"],
             Salary = (decimal)row["Salary"],
             HireDate = (DateTime)row["HireDate"],
             Weight = (int)row["Weight"],
             HeightInInches = (int)row["Height"]
        };
    }
}
```

If you find yourself working with DataReaders, you can make a similar `FromDataRecord(IDataRecord row)` method (it greatly annoys me the ADO.Net team used two different interfaces here).

This lets me quickly and easily convert query results to a strongly-typed object in a repeatable way. For larger projects, I may move these conversion methods to their own static class (or logically-grouped classes, possibly within their own class library project) to live closer to the data layer. However, you want to be careful of your dependency chain here, because those classes have dependencies in both directions (towards to the user, to know about the `Employee` type, and towards the database, to know about the query format).

Comment: I'd prefer `Convert.ToInt32` over direct casting here. Then you handle cases like if the value is actually `"1"` or if it's an `UInt32` intstead. But better to use `Field`-method directly, to support also nullable types.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I understand the argument, but since SQL Server itself is strongly typed, in my experience this doesn't happen, or in the rare cases it does I'd call it an error in schema design and either fix it in the schema or the in the SQL for that query, to return the correct type. I do admit NULL  can be awkward with this pattern, though.

Comment: you can use any rdbms as source for a DataTable(even excel).